# Can I use partition relation tables?

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-partitioning

Currently, I have one Table A (parent) with primary key as 'KeyID'. This table has 2 children-tables B and C. In table B, it has foreign key 'KeyID'. Same for table C. Below is schema for 3 tables:

- tblA (KeyID, POName, DateReceiver, Desc)
- tblB (subkeyID, KeyID, ItemName, Desc)
- tblC (subkey2ID, KeyID, ShipName, Desc)

The relationships are one-to-many

So, with the relationship among these tables:

1. Can we use 'partition table' feature in MS SQL Server 2008 **for these 3 tables**?
2. If I partition tblA for Column DateReceiver, how can I partition for 2 tables tblB and tblC? which column at tblB and tblC will be used?

Please advice.

Thank you very much.

Comment: here which table you want to partition?

Comment: What is the motivation for partitioning?

Comment: Are the relationships many-to-one (B -> A and C -> A) or one-to-one?

Comment: is there anyone knows about this? please help me. Thanks.